# How to loop a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code where a sentence is typed word by word on the HTML page and then resets and repeats.

This is the code I am using:

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Welcome';
var speed = 70;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

var x = 0;
while (x = 0){
  typeWriter()
}
```

Whenever I use this code nothing happens, but when I use `window.onload = typeWriter;` it works only once. I want to loop, how can I do this?

Example:

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Welcome';
var speed = 70;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
window.onload = typeWriter;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Welcome';
var speed = 70;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }else{
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    i = 0;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

window.onload = typeWriter;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to repeat the execution, here is a working snippet:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Welcome';
var speed = 70;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  i = 0;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
  typeWriter();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typing mistake. Change the following section of code

```
while (x = 0){
      typeWriter()
}
```

to

```
while (x == 0){
      typeWriter()
}
```

because x=0 is not logical operator, it's an assignment operator.